# Convert Lat/Lon to xx.x N xxx.x W

Tags: java

I've tried looking around, but I can't seem to find
any formula to do the conversion.
I want to convert a Lat/Lon, like:
`-121.5    18.0`
to:
 `xx.x N    xxx.x W`

Is it just converting to Hour Min Sec, and just using  'Hour.Min'?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the ```dd.ddd N``` decimal degrees format, the ```dd mm.m N``` degrees and decimal muntes format, the ```dd mm N``` degrees and rounded minutes format, another format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take, for example, -121.5 latitude.

The degrees are the integral part (in absolute value) - in this case, 121 degrees.

The minutes are the fractional part (also in absolute value) times 60 (because there are 60 minutes in a degree) - in this case, 30 minutes.

Repeat for seconds, if needed.

Finally, if the latitude is positive, it's North, otherwise it's South.

So, latitude `-121.5` is `121 degrees 30 minutes South`.

The conversion to Java is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

From degrees.minutes.seconds direction to decimal degrees it is:

```
decimal degrees = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600
```

if the direction is south or east you add the minus sign.

From decimals to degrees.minutes.seconds direction its:

```
degrees = truncate(|decimal degrees|)
seconds = truncate(|decimal degrees| *60) modulo 60
minutes = truncate(|decimal degrees| * 3600) modulo 3600
```

If decimal degrees were negative you add either south or east.